# MongoDB add weights to index based on search order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, search, indexing, text

Let's say I have a schema with an index of:

```
Person.index({ name: 'text', occupation: 'text', country: 'text' })
```

and a collection of Person documents such as:

```
[
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    occupation: 'Doctor',
    country: 'Canada'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary Smith',
    occupation: 'Doctor',
    country: 'Brazil'
  }
]
```

When I query with a search term like the following:

```
PersonModel.find(
  { $text: { $search: 'Mary Doctor Canada' } }, 
  { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } }
).sort(
  { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } }
)
```

How can I ensure that the first word in the search term has a higher importance than that of the following? In this instance, how can I make it that "Mary" is received a higher text score than "Canada" in the search term?

Similarly, if the search term was instead "Brazil John", then how can I make sure that Mary receives the higher text score, since the term "Brazil" comes before "John"?